# P-type Schottky diode forward bias direction

Tags: diodes, schottky

For n-type Schottky diodes, when we apply forward bias (positive voltage on metal side), electrons start flowing from semiconductor to metal.

Similarly for p-type Schottky diodes, holes start flowing from semiconductor to metal.

But, when we say forward biasing p-type Schottky diodes, does that mean applying positive voltage on metal or negative voltage on metal?

Comment: Is there such a thing? I suspect the inherent properties of metals do not allow a Schottky diode to exist with p-doped silicon.

Comment: @DKNguyen There is. If silicon is p-doped, the work function of the silicon will be generally larger than the work function of the metal, and in this case, the energy band will bend downwards near the junction, creating a barrier (built-in voltage) for holes.